# PostgreSql streaming replication - table not created on the slave

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSql replication.

I tried to set up streaming replication, and at the end I created a database on the master, which I could afterwards see on the slave.
However, when I created a table on the master, it is not replicated to the slave.

Checking the table pg_stat_replication on the master, it looks OK as far as I can understand:

```
select usename,application_name,client_addr,backend_start,state,sync_state from pg_stat_replication ;
      usename   | application_name | client_addr |         backend_start         |   state   | sync_state
    ------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------
     replicator | walreceiver      | 10.97.7.150 | 2020-06-28 20:48:15.463922+03 | streaming | async

select client_addr, state, sent_lsn, write_lsn,replitest,flush_lsn, replay_lsn from pg_stat_replication;
 client_addr |   state   |  sent_lsn  | write_lsn  | flush_lsn  | replay_lsn
-------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 10.97.7.150 | streaming | 0/2701AFB8 | 0/2701AFB8 | 0/2701AFB8 | 0/2701AFB8
```

On the slave side I see this:

```
SELECT pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();
 pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2020-06-28 20:52:22.915897+03

 select pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery
-------------------
 t
```

Still when I create a table, I cannot find her on the slave side.

What should I check further?

Comment: Did you commit the transaction which created the table?

Comment: Create table is DDL - should it be committed? Also, I thought that in postgresql commit is automatic.

Comment: Yes, most DDL is not visible until committed.  Whether commit is automatic is up to your connection library.  psycopg2, for example, famously does not autocommit by default, nor does it warn you if you abandon an uncommitted transaction.